# Using cakephp's Auth component with salted password hashes

Tags: php, security, cakephp

How can I make the Auth component of cakephp create, use and store a random salt with the password?

Comment: If anybody finds this and wants to do the same thing with CakePHP 2.x, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509655/cakephp-2-override-authcomponents-password-method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start here http://book.cakephp.org/view/566/Change-Hash-Function , and set the `$authenticate` variable to your user model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    function hashPasswords($data) {
        if (isset($data['User']['password'])) {
            //Get the user to get the salt
            $user = $this->findByUsername($data['User']['username']);
            //Let's say you have a "salt" field in your db 
            $data['User']['password'] = md5($data['User']['password'].$user['User']['salt']);
            return $data;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in Auth component. Take a look at [Random String generator CakePHP component](http://planetcakephp.org/aggregator/items/3400-updated-random-string-generator-cakephp-component).

Answer (score 0):

Look into overriding the hash function used by the Auth component as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1254/Change-Hash-Function).